# Regexp: Specific characters in the text

Tags: java, regex

My goal is to validate specific characters **(*,^,+,?,$,[],[^])** in the some text, like:

```
?test.test => true
test.test  => false

test^test => true
test:test => false

test-test$ => true
test-test  => false
```

I've already created regex regarding to requirment above, but I am not sure in this.

```
^(.*)([\[\]\^\$\?\*\+])(.*)$
```

Will be good to know whether it can be optimized in such way.

Comment: You don't need to escape `^`, `$`, `?`, `*`, `+` which a character class.

Comment: which programming language?

Comment: I've alredy specified tag (java).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regex is already optimized one as its very simple. You can make is much simpler or readable only.

Also if you use the `matches()` method of Java's `String` class then you'll not require the `^` and `$` at the both ends.

```
.*([\\[\\]^$?*+]).*
```

Double slashes(`\\`) for Java, otherwise please use single slash(`\`).

Look, I have removed the captures `()` along with escape character `\` for the characters `^$?*+` as they are inside the character class `[]`.

Comment: Is there difference between `matches()` and `find()` in java, except the added `^$`? If not, you should really consider using `find()` and getting rid of the last `.*` (first one is arguable to me, see my answer, but the last one sure doesn't serve *any* purpose whatsoever)

Comment: @Robin I din't see any `find()` method under the `String` class.

Comment: @SabujHassan: yep, seems to be a [java.util.regex.Matcher](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find()) method. Since OP didn't specify the way he wants to call the regex, might be relevant. I don't know the implementation differences between the two (string's matches and Matcher's find) though.

Comment: @Robin `matches()` expects the regex to be the exact of string. For example `\d` with return false for `xyz10abc` with `matches()` but will return success for `Matcher`. For `matcher()` you have to change the regex into `.*\d+.*`.

Comment: @SabujHassan: Yes, I know that. I was talking about differences that impact the speed at which the regex is processed in both methods: if there are the same I believe `find()` can give quicker results.

Answer (score 2):

**TL;DR**

The quickest regex to do the job is

```
# ^[^\]\[^$?*+]*([\]\[^$?*+])

^               #start of the string
[^              #any character BUT...
    \]\[^$?*+   #...these ones (^$?*+ aren't special inside a character class)
]*+             #zero or more times (possessive quantifier)
([              #capture any of...
    \]\[^$?*+   #...these characters
])
```

Be careful that in a java string, you need to escape the `\` as well, so you should transform every `\` into `\\`.

**Discussion**

At first two regex come in mind:

- `[\]\[^$?*+]`, which will match only the character you want inside the string.
- `^.*[\]\[^$?*+]`, which will match your string up to the desired character.

It's actually important performance-wise to understand the difference between the case with `.*` at the beginning and the one with no wildcard at all.

When searching for the pattern, the first `.*` will make the regex engine *eat all the string*, then backtrack character by character to see if it's a match for your character range `[...]`. So the regex will actually search *from the end of the string*.

This is an advantage when your wanted sign if near the end, a disadvantage when it is at the beginning.

On the other case, the regex engine will try every character, beginning from the left, until it matches what you want.

You can see what I mean with these two examples from the excellent regex101.com:

- with the `.*`, match is found in 26 steps when near the beginning, 8 when it's near the beginning: http://regex101.com/r/oI3pS1/#debugger
- without it, it is found in 5 steps [when near the beginning](http://regex101.com/r/jD8jV7/#debugger) and 23 [when near the end](http://regex101.com/r/eM0rA9/#debugger)

Now, if you want to combine these two approaches you can use the tl;dr answer: you eat everything that *isn't* your character, then you match your character (or fail if there isn't one).

On [our example](http://regex101.com/r/oT8uO0/#debugger), it takes 7 steps wherever your character is in the string (and 7 steps even if there is no character, thanks to the possessive quantifier).

Comment: It does not compile for me.

Comment: Then I guess in Java you do have to escape the `][`, this behavior sometimes depends on the regex flavor you're using.

Comment: @fashuser: Edited. That's probably a little more than what you asked but regex are fun.

Answer (score 1):

That should also work:

```
String regex = ".*[\\[\\]^$?*+].*";

String test1 = "?test.test";
String test2 = "test.test";
String test3 = "test^test";
String test4 = "test:test";
String test5 = "test-test$";
String test6 = "test-test";

System.out.println(test1.matches(regex));
System.out.println(test2.matches(regex));
System.out.println(test3.matches(regex));
System.out.println(test4.matches(regex));
System.out.println(test5.matches(regex));
System.out.println(test6.matches(regex));
```